# OwlCarousel2 number of items wordpress

Tags: wordpress, owl-carousel-2

It shows all testimonials but I want to show just one

When I checked classed I found, it's give all dives have class['client'] give them class ['active']

[image]

```
    $(function () {
   "use strict";

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".client").owlCarousel();
    loop:true;
    items:1;
    nav:true;
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `singleItem` to the owlCarousel, also the properties should be separated with commas, not semicolons.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    "use strict";
    $(".client").owlCarousel({
        loop: true,
        items: 1,
        nav: true,
        singleItem: true
    });
});
```